# Table cannot be created with the following data. Syntax error occurs

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
Create      Table       employees (
emp_id          char(5)         not null,
hourly_pay      integer         not null,
emp_name        varchar(30)     not null,
emp_address     varchar(50)     not null,
gender          char(1)         not null,
email           varchar(30)     null,
contact_info    integer         not null,
outlet_id       char(5)         null,
supervisor_id   char(5)         null,
job             varchar(15)     not null,
PRIMARY     KEY (emp_id)
FOREIGN     KEY (supervisor_id) 
REFERENCES  employees(emp_id)
)
```

Data as shown above. SQL Server 2008 keeps throwing up an error of "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOREIGN'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a comma.

```
Create      Table       employees (
emp_id          char(5)         not null,
hourly_pay      integer         not null,
emp_name        varchar(30)     not null,
emp_address     varchar(50)     not null,
gender          char(1)         not null,
email           varchar(30)     null,
contact_info    integer         not null,
outlet_id       char(5)         null,
supervisor_id   char(5)         null,
job             varchar(15)     not null,

PRIMARY     KEY (emp_id),
------------------------^

FOREIGN     KEY (supervisor_id) REFERENCES  employees(emp_id)
)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Can't believe I spent 30mins+, failing to spot that comma.

Comment: @TheKraven that's too bad. The error message even told you almost precisely where to look. :-)